# Is possible to reinitialize bitset from STL with string?

Tags: c++, stl, bitset

Is it possible to reinitialize bitset with string?
I have a simple class like this:

```
class Bits{
  public:
  bitset<1024>b;
};
```

Is it possible that later I get a string and in code I set bits with the string (string is 1024 length and only 1 and 0)?

```
Bits c;
c.b.something(string);
```

Comment: What's with the good old art of [looking things up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)? wouldn't this have been much less work than writing and reviewing a proper SO question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, simplest is:

```
b = bitset<1024>(some_string_form);
```